# Kivy Slider Touch Input Area Too Large

Tags: python, slider, kivy

I am trying to create a game using Kivy, and when I tried to use the Slider widget, I could not get it to stop reacting to nearby touch inputs. I looked online and could not find any way to control the area the widget reacts to. Any help would be appreciated! Below is a very simple Kivy Slider app I made to try and isolate a solution.

Test.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
Window.size = (375,375)
Builder.load_file('Test.kv')
sm=ScreenManager()
class SliderScreen(Screen):
    pass    
class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
sm.add_widget(SliderScreen(name='sliderscreen'))
Test().run()
```

Test.kv:

```
<SliderScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Slider:
            pos_hint:{'x':.15,'y':.275}
            size_hint:.75,.25
            value_track:True
            background_width: 10
            value_track_color: 0,.4,.8,1
            min:0
            sensitivity: 'handle'
            max: 300
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think we may need a bit more info to help you. I have run your posted code and I don't see any reaction to touch events (other than touch and drag on the slider handle). If you are using `on_touch` events in addition to what you show in your posted code, be aware that `touch` events are propagated to all widgets, so you may need to do a collision test to determine if it is a touch on the `Slider` or not. Have a look at 'Widget touch event bubbling' and `collide_point()` in [Widget docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html).

Comment: Clarification: The issue is that when I touch near the slider (clearly not on any part of it) it still reacts as if I am touching the slider. If i press above the slider and drag horizontally, it slides (despite me not actually pressing it). It is not an issue with other widgets because there are none (this is all of the code above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for the answer, if you don't want to visually modify your widget is to override the `collide_point()` method, which handles touch input.

To do so, you need to create a custom widget class as follow :

```
class CustomSlider(Slider):
    def collide_point(self, x, y):
        return self.x <= x <= self.right and self.y+40 <= y <= self.top-40
```

What this does is, it changes the condition that validates the touch inside the Widget. The modification checks for a smaller area than the actual widget. If these value don't work for you, feel free to experiment, the code is pretty self-explanatory.